# Insert a record in aspnet_Users, aspnet_Membership using an sql script

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a SQL script to populate the database with roles and users. This script will be run on several machines because there are multiple developers for the project it will be use to. The problem is if I created the users using ASP.NET Configuration (VS2010), exported the script and executed it on another machine, then the MembershipProvider will not validate the users, maybe because of the unique machine key use to generate the salt.

I tried invoking the `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` stored procedure but can't get it work.
I also tried manually inserting a record in `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Membership` but validation also failed, same reason as stated above.

Any idea or workaround?

Comment: Are you trying this in same project? (I mean same project deployed on different computers) Or Different projects?

Comment: @WaqasRaja, yes same project deployed on different machines (localhost - IIS). Marek, I'm unable to call aspnet_Membership_CreateUser because of the UTCDate parameter.

Comment: @Marek, I'm unable to call aspnet_Membership_CreateUser because of the UTCDate parameter.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz, I'm able to call the stored procedure now, but after the user is created. MembershipProvider.Validate user will failed on the new user created by this method. I can see the record properly inserted on aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership. Note, I've hardcoded the passwordSalt value. I see the password is not automatically encrypted, even though I've specified the password salt and format.

Comment: @czetsuya That's right - [the procedure does not hash or encrypt the password, it only inserts the data](http://www.adivo.com/samples/database/aspnetdb/PR-ASPNETDB-aspnet_Membership_CreateUser.htm). When you use the `Membership.CreateUser` method, it calls an [internal method that performs the hashing/encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3785627/95).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the **MembershipSeeder** utility [available from CodePlex](http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/7450) (executable, source code and documentation).

However, the problem you described is weird. There should be no problem to create the users on one machine, script the table data and then execute the `INSERT` statements to re-create the users on a different machine. The salt values are not tied to a machine.

Comment: I've already encountered the same issue 2 times, that's why I thought something could be related to the machine. Same project, same web.config, same sql script, but validation won't work on the second machine. Actually, on the first machine I created the user using ASP.NET Configuration (VS2010), export the sql script and execute on the second machine. @Marek, correct me if I'm wrong but I think MembershipSeeder is the same as ASP.NET Configuration from VS? (VS->Project->ASP.Net Configuration)

Comment: @czetsuya I don't think so. Have you seen the screenshots in the documentation file `MembershipSeeder - Readme.docx`? Can you post the SQL script you export?

Comment: here's the sql generated: INSERT INTO aspnet_Users VALUES ((select top 1 ApplicationId from aspnet_Applications where ApplicationName = 'myApp'), newid(), 'myEmail', 'myEmail', '', 0, getdate())

Comment: For aspnet_Membership: INSERT INTO aspnet_Membership VALUES ((select top 1 ApplicationId from aspnet_Applications where ApplicationName = 'myApp'), (select top 1 UserId from aspnet_Users where username='myEmail'), 'jUfBZkOdbxhZ9ADsei5oP1EHmhs=', 1, 'c5xpd39NAe8BMm6g3D5m3e9/LHI=',NULL, 'myEmail','myEmail', 'Secret Question', 'secretAnswer', 1, 0, getdate(), getdate(), getdate(), getdate(), 0, getdate(), 0,getdate(), NULL
)

Comment: thanks for the help it's now working. The culprit is my method override when creating the user, 1 has a default value for IsApproved=false. Causing validation to fail.