# Simple Membership: can I create a user without referencing webmatrix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have my restrictions to not to reference webmatrix here.

I want to create a user record in membership tables of simple membership (using EF 5).
To make it easier, I have mapped EF Models to those tables.

**Is it possible to with code without webmatrix ?**

---

### EDIT

I don't want to use any membership provider.

### EDIT

The system uses simple membership. I don't want to change that. From a separate project, I want to add a user to that database without referencing WebMatrix. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use SimpleMembership without WebMatrix as SimpleMembership lives in the WebMatrix namespace.

You can, however, use any number of other membership providers, such as the original SqlMembershipProvider, the Universal Providers, or any number others that are available.

EDIT:

Yes, you can add a user to the database manually.  In the comments below I have included a link to the source for SimpleMembershipProvider.cs, examine that code and use the same methods in your own project.

Comment: I cant use any membership provider.

Comment: @bilalfazlani - Then you have a dichotomy.  SimpleMembership lives in the WebMatrix namespace.  It lives in the `Webmatrix.WebData.dll`.  It's namespace is `WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider`  You can see this in the source code http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs .  It is *impossible* to use SimpleMembership without referencing WebMatrix.

Answer (score 1):

With standard ASP.NET membership you can create new user with [System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es.aspx).

Comment: I cant use any membership provider.

Comment: You may implement your own custom membership provider. In general case you even don't need standard membership tables. Look at this articles: 1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Let me explain correctly. The system uses simple membership. I don't want to change that. From a separate project, I want to add a user to that database without referencing WebMatrix. Is that possible ?

Comment: Sure, you just need to insert correct data to standard table. The easiest way might be to use built-in stored procedure like aspnet_Membership_CreateUser, but you need to prepare data for it (encrypt the password). There is a good advice here how to prepare password: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771326/password-for-aspnet-membership-createuser/3785627#3785627. Also you may use Reflector to analyze code in standard Membership provider and copy its part to your application.

Comment: @VitaliyShibaev - SimpleMembership doesn't use Stored procedures, it's all in code, and the aspnet_* stored procs don't exist.. even if you were to use them, they wouldn't work because the table definitions are different.